# How do I expand a dataframe of array of struct and filter based on the length of unique items in each row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe of type 
`[value: array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>>]`
I want to add a new column to this dataframe, which includes the length of all the unique elements retrieved by expanding all the tuples in each row. My primary purpose is to drop the row when this length is greater than a certain value.

What I have so far is just the length for each row - code shown below

```
 val size = inputDF.rdd.map(_.getSeq[Row](0)).map(x => {
      val aSet = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
      x.map {
        case Row(aa: String, bb: String) =>
          aSet += aa
          aSet += bb
      }
      (aSet.size)
    })
```

However when I try to add this as a new column to the inputDF data, it does not work.

Sample inputDF is:

```
val inputDF = Seq(
        (Array(("A","B"))),
        (Array(("C","D"),("C","E"),("D","F"),("F","G"),("G","H"))),
        (Array(("C","D"))),
        (Array(("P","Q"),("R","S"),("T","U"),("T","V")))
     ).toDF
```

And the expected column to be appended to this has values - 2,6,2,7

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spark version 2.4.0 or greater, then you can do the same without using UDF (which is supposed to be more optimized solution):

```
scala> inputDF.selectExpr("*", "size(array_distinct(flatten(transform(value, (v, i) -> array(v._1, v._2))))) as count").show(false)
+----------------------------------------+-----+
|value                                   |count|
+----------------------------------------+-----+
|[[A, B]]                                |2    |
|[[C, D], [C, E], [D, F], [F, G], [G, H]]|6    |
|[[C, D]]                                |2    |
|[[P, Q], [R, S], [T, U], [T, V]]        |7    |
+----------------------------------------+-----+
```

Read more about Apache Spark higher order functions:
https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a UDF that `fold`s the struct elements into a `Set` and returns its `size`, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = Seq(
  Seq(("a", "b"), ("b", "c")),
  Seq(("d", "e"), ("f", "g"), ("g", "h")),
  Seq(("i", "j"))
).toDF("c1")

val distinctElemCount = udf{ (arr: Seq[Row]) =>
  arr.foldLeft(Set.empty[String])(
    (acc, r) => acc + r.getString(0) + r.getString(1)
  ).size
}

df.withColumn("count", distinctElemCount($"c1")).show(false)
// +------------------------+-----+
// |c1                      |count|
// +------------------------+-----+
// |[[a, b], [b, c]]        |3    |
// |[[d, e], [f, g], [g, h]]|5    |
// |[[i, j]]                |2    |
// +------------------------+-----+
```